# Macro to interact with target?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft, is there an equivalent that you can use in a macro to 'Interact With Target' so that I can create a macro that interacts with specific NPCs with a single keypress?

[image]

Comment: The command to do this has been a protected function since ~2.3.3.
If you are able to get the command to go through, you'll get autobanned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no macro for that. You must use the keybinding. Ostensibly, this is to curtail automation that would be outside the bounds of the WoW Terms of Service.